# Why we can't have a thermodynamical system with zero intensive properties?

Tags: thermodynamics

How to prove whether it is impossible or not for a system to have zero intensive properties?

I recently saw this question on some website, where the answer were given as:

> every system will have a freezing point, a melting point, and so on.

But my question is, how to prove even that? Can it be possible in the future to invent a system with none such "points"?

So, how can we prove that it is really impossible to invent a system with no freezing point?

This requires a proof, that *a system can not have zero intensive properties.* How can we deduce it?

Comment: As far I know, the intensive and the extensive properties are coming in pairs. If the system wouldn't have an intensive property, then it wouldn't have also an extensive one, so it wouldn't have properties. From thermodinamical view, it would be non-existent.

Comment: Liquid helium doesn't freeze, does it? Instead, it becomes a superfluid. A superfluid is a system with a collective behavior and as such does not have a random motion of atoms or molecules and therefore does not have a temperature. You cannot cool down or warm up a superfluid. it would stop being a superfluid before it warms up. So cooling it down would not freeze it either.

Comment: @safesphere By applying a higher pressure than atmospheric Helium can freeze. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium#Liquid_helium

Comment: You seem to be asking two separate questions. I do not see an obvious link between the statement that a system has not freezing and melting points (or more generally phase transitions) and the statement that a system has no intensive properties. For example an ideal gas has intensive properties (temperature and pressure for example) but only one phase.

Comment: Given an extensive property of a system I can define an intensive by dividing by the system size. For example the (extensive) heat capacity can be used to define the (intensive) specific heat capacity by dividing by the mass. Intensive versions of the entropy, internal energy and free energy are also routinely used.

Comment: @BySymmetry What is the intensive version of volume? 1? :-)

Comment: @peterh That would be specific volume. And intensive version of mass? Why of course, that would be density :-)